# How to send a Composer item to bottom in QGIS?

Tags: python, plugins, methods, qgis

I'm trying to create a composer with pyQGIS.
I can create composer maps, scalebars, legends, etc., but i don't know how to bring an item forward, or send it backward.
Even in the API documentation, I can't find a method to do it.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to send a layer or a picture/object forward/backward?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I'm trying to send the composer map backward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer to my own question.
I finally found moveItemToBottom() and moveSelectedItemsToBottom() methods.

It gives :

```
self.composerMap = QgsComposerMap(self.composition, 5,2,408,286)
self.composition.addComposerMap(self.composerMap)
self.composition.moveItemToBottom(self.composerMap)
self.composition.moveSelectedItemsToBottom()
```

I don't know why, but I need the 2 methods (moveItemBottom and moveSelectdItemsToBottom) for the composerMap being send backward.